# Multiple select statements, not the same amount of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am trying to select a position and then the report line next to it.

My query is:

```
SELECT (SELECT pos.PositionId
FROM PositionData pos
WHERE pos.PositionId = 1234) as [Topmost],
(SELECT pos.PositionId
FROM PositionData pos
WHERE pos.pdOpsReportLine = 1234) as [Reportline]
```

The error im getting is:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Now I know what this error means.

But I dont want to use a TOP statement as I want the rows returned in the 2nd column.

**NOTE:** The below statements are supposed to be columns in sql server.

What I **want** is this:

```
Topmost        Reportline
1234           2345
               3456
               4567
               5678
```

What I **don't want** is this:

```
Topmost
1234
2345
3456
4567
5678
```

Where topmost is the topmost selected employee like the CEO and reportline are the people that report to him.

Comment: That's really about *formatting* the output into a particular report structure, and would be better dealt with by reporting tools or other presentation code, rather than trying to mangle it together in SQL.

Comment: Which SQL server are you using - 2008 or 2012? 2012 has functions to do this that SQL 2008 does not.

Comment: Currently I am using SQL server 2012. But report builder is going to call this in a PROC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to get all your data in such a formatting, you can do this:

```
select
    case
       when row_number() over(partition by pos.PositionId order by pos1.pdOpsReportLine) = 1 then
           pos.PositionId
       else
           null
    end as [Topmost],
    pos1.PositionId as [Reportline]
from PositionData as pos
    left outer join PositionData pos1 on pos.PositionId = pos1.pdOpsReportLine
where pos.pdOpsReportLine is null
order by pos.PositionId, pos1.pdOpsReportLine
```

see [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b3cc/2) example

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Declare @Topmost int=1234,
@MinPositionId int 


SELECT @MinPositionId=min(pos.PositionId)
FROM PositionData pos
WHERE pos.pdOpsReportLine = @Topmost

select @Topmost Topmost,@MinPositionId Reportline

Union all

SELECT '',pos.PositionId
FROM PositionData pos
WHERE pos.pdOpsReportLine = @Topmost 
and pos.PositionId != @MinPositionId
```